# Different questions for same problem in different language - duplicate or not?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

Recently I came across the same problem statement being asked in two different questions but with different language tags. My question is whether to consider those questions as duplicate or not?

My initial thought : they are duplicate. all those languages could have been specified in the same question.

But OP's argument stats that *If I ask the same question about something in one language and another, these should in my opinion be in separate questions since the answer concerns (a) a different audience, and (b) would likely be quit different.*

Thanks argument was little convincing but I am still not sure. Can you please share your views?

**EDIT**

SO question : [appending-two-csv-files-together-via-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951820/appending-two-csv-files-together-via-columns) - targeting `shell`

Possible duplicate : [appending-two-csv-files-column-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948526/appending-two-csv-files-column-wise) - targeting `python`

**Note** that referred questions are exactly same from the same OP. with just a difference of tag

Another observation: OP doesn't show his/her effort and just tries to get it solved in different possible ways. Am I missing something?

**P.S.** I am quite new to meta so suggestion to improve communication here would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the question. Honestly if the answer is the same regardless of programming language being used, it's probably not a very good programming question to begin with (but without seeing the question it's impossible to say.)

Comment: Updated question with links to referred question.

Comment: The bash version of the question isn't necessarily a duplicate, but it looks like a gimme teh codez question.

Comment: For this very discussion, I've a very good example, which I marked as duplicate, though they were tagged *a bit* differently. [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19950477/2024761) and [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19951338/2024761).

Comment: @R.J yeah I am observing this trend. Getting annoyed especially when I posted solution to first question and the same appears again in question list.

Comment: @Wooble that's where I got confused. otherwise many a times I was quite convinced to mark such questions duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having a real example here I answer the general question.

#### The same question with different tags is not a duplicate.

Example:

> How to extract the first 2 characters of a string?

The answer to that is totally different for each programming language.

### Update

Since the OP of one question mentioned a bash solution would be OK for him too, I would tag this question with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) too and that makes both questions having the same relevant tag.

Comment: OP mentions a bash solution would be OK. I would tag those 2 questions with `bash`

Comment: thanks for you opinion. Can you please update this in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think two questions may be very similar in their context but a closer look should help you judge.

Example

[VBA what is the longest allowed name for a function or procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075164/vba-what-is-the-longest-allowed-name-for-a-function-or-procedure)

This question is about VBA. It does have a vote as being a duplicate of

[Maximum Method Name Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425988/maximum-method-name-length)

(*omit the other 3 votes and the quality of the Q itself*)

I have had this question in my close votes queue earlier this morning. At first it did kind of seem like a duplicate but then I had a closer look and read the entire question (*2nd one*) and it became kind of obvious that they should **not be marked as duplicates**.

Comment: Thanks for your views. Please note that referred questions are exactly same from the same OP. with just a difference of tag.